# How to use child type where abstract parent type is expected

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, covariance, contravariance

This may be more of a covariance/contravariance issue. But I have the following classes:

```
public interface IOutputPort<in TUseCaseResponse>
{
    void Handle(TUseCaseResponse response);
}

//Abstract parent
public abstract class Response
{
}

//Concrete child
public class GenericResponse : Response
{
}

internal class MockPresenter<TResponse> : IOutputPort<TResponse> where TResponse : Response
{
    public void Handle(TResponse response)
    {
    }
}

public class LocationStore
{
    public void DoThing(IOutputPort<Response> outputPort)
    {
    }
}
```

The idea is that `LocationStore` should be able to accept an `IOutputPort` object that has a generic type that at least inherits from `Response`

I then try to call my function similar to:

```
var genericPresenter = new MockPresenter<GenericResponse>();
var store = new LocationStore();

store.DoThing(genericPresenter);
```

But the compiler complains that `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MockPresenter<GenericResponse> to 'IOutputPort<Response>'`

Even if I remove the contravariant modifier from `IOutputPort` I still get the same error. I might be missing something pretty obvious here, but I'm feeling a bit stuck. How do I design my `DoThing` method to accept an `IOutputPort` that can have any type inheriting from `Response`?

Passing in a generic as a type argument to `LocationStore` isn't an option, because the same instance needs to be able to call `DoThing` with several different output ports.

Comment: For this code to compile you need to change it to use the `out` keyword. But this might give you problems depending on how `IOutputPort` evolves. Not quite sure why it works with `out` and not `in`. Hopefully some one else will explain it :)

Comment: I edited my original code to show why I can't change it to ```out```

Comment: Could you use: `var genericPresenter = new MockPresenter<Response>();` instead?

Comment: @Michael, the problem with that is I need access to all my properties inside ```GenericResponse``` once ```DoThing``` returns, or any other type argument I use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the easy solution is to just make `DoThing` generic:

```
public void DoThing<TResponse>(IOutputPort<TResponse> outputPort) where TResponse : Response
{
}
```

This makes it compile, and hopefully provide the functionality you need.

As for why your design was not allowed consider the following:

```
public class OutputPort<T>: IOutputPort<T>
{
    private List<T> _innerList;

    public void Handle(T response)
    {
        _innerList.Add(response);
    }
}
```

Now if `T` is `GenericResponse` and you would be able to cast it to `IOutputPort<Response>` suddenly you would be able to add a `Response` to the `List<GenericResponse>` which hopefully is clear why it isn't allowed.

Comment: So far this seems to work. I forgot you can specify generics on a method instead of just the class! Also surprised the compiler implicitly infers the generic type when I call ```DoThing``` and doesn't have me explicitly specify it